# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘values’ for signature ‘"hash"’

Tags: r, hash

I'm looking to create keys and then pull all the values onto one list, however, when I try to pull the values I'm getting this error:

```
    Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘values’ for signature ‘"hash"’
```

Not sure if its a formatting issue or something. Here's my current code:

```
     myMarkersList <- hash("Neuron", c("Snap25","Meg3"))
     myMarkersList$GABAergic <- c("Ndnf","Vip")
     myMarkersList$Microglia <- c("Ctss","Csf1r")
     myMarkersList$Astrocytes <- c("Gfap","Aqp4")
     myMarkersList$Endothelial <- c("Xdh","Flt1")
     myMarkersList$OPC <- c("Pdgfra")
     myMarkersList$Oligodendrocyte <- c("Opalin","Olig1")
     myMarkersList$Glutamatergic <- c("Ptgs2", "Ngb")

     myGenesList <- values(myMarkersList)
     myMarkers <-c()
```

I get the error in trying to create myGenesList

Comment: Please, insert the packages you are using. `hash` is not from `base` R.

Comment: You should be clear about what package you are getting the `hash` function from (that's not a base R thing).

Comment: After loading the `hash` package, I don't get any error.